# AngularJS dynamic forms with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-forms

i am working with AngularJS dynamic forms . According to my userid value i generated multiple form field with same model name using ng-repeat. i am not able to get this input model values due to this ng-repeat. in this example i am using static userid data.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form role="form" name='userForm' novalidate>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="myid in userid">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>ID</label>
                        <input ng-model="myid" id="myid" name="myid" placeholder="Enter bugid" type="text" required readonly disabled>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Comments</label>
                        <textarea ng-model="manualComment" id="textarea1" rows="1" required></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 ">
                        <label>Gender</label>

                        <select ng-model="gender" name="select2" required>
                            <option value="male">Male</option>
                            <option value="female">Female</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttonContainer text-center btn-container">
            <br>
            <button ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" type="button" id="adduser" ng-click="adduser">Add user</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn button--default btn--small pull-center">Close</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

my js code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
 myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.userid = [1, 2, 3];
   $sope.adduser = function() {

}
});
```

i need to send array of objects to my server.my userid also dynamic it has more than 100 data. how can i get each and every data field model value? and how to convert those model data into array of objects like my sampleserver data?

i am expecting my final output data like this

```
var sampleServerData = [{
        "userid": 1,
        "manualcomment": "mycmt1",
        "gender": "male"
    }, {
        "userid": 2,
        "manualcomment": "mycmt2",
        "gender": "male"
    }, {
        "userid": 3,
        "manualcomment": "mycmt3",
        "gender": "female"
    }]
```

Comment: Are you not getting your data as an array of objects already?

Comment: no i didn't get any array of objects .even though i didn't get any  model value from this form . i am getting array of user id's from my previous page . Here i gave only static data for my userid. according to this userid i am generating form . i am also mention my expected final output data. can please send sample fiddle for this .

Answer (score 0):

You should change your textarea **id** to a **class** or create a textarea id in your user object(more on that below).

If the id's you have to work with are in an array, then create an array of objects based on you ids array.

```
var ids = [1, 2, 3];
var users = ids.map(function(id) {
   return {id: id, comment: "", gender: ""};
})
```

I think I have a solution for you, I made you a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/zayiwotaha/edit?html,js,output). Make sure you hit the **run with js** button, for some reason it doesn't run onload.

#### HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form role="form" name='userForm' novalidate>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="user in users">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>ID</label>
                        <input ng-model="user.id" id="user.id" name="user.id" placeholder="Enter bugid" type="text" required readonly disabled>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Comments</label>
                        <textarea ng-model="user.comment" id="textarea1" rows="1" required></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 ">
                        <label>Gender</label>

                        <select ng-model="user.gender" name="select2" required>
                            <option value="male">Male</option>
                            <option value="female">Female</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttonContainer text-center btn-container">
            <br>
            <button ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" type="button" id="adduser" ng-click="adduser()">Add user</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn button--default btn--small pull-center">Close</button>
        </div>
    </form>
 </div>
```

#### JS

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
     myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.ids = [1, 2, 3];
   
      $scope.users = $scope.ids.map(function(id) {
        return {id: id, comment: "", gender: ""};
      });

      $scope.adduser = function() {
        var data = $scope.users.map(function(user) {
          return {
           "userid": user.id,
           "manualcomment": user.comment,
           "gender": user.gender
          }
      });
     
      console.log("data", data)
  }
});
```

Comment: This answer is very helpful for me . According to my new requirement i need load first option value in select box by default once page is running .Your answer code  inside gender i need to load first value. in future instead of gender i will load more than 100 option value inside that select box. by default first option value should be load in that select box .can you please send that fiddle example .

Comment: here i am getting 3 forms .i need to delete 2nd form and other 2 form data i need print . how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file you can call ng-repeat like this;

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <form role="form" name='userForm' novalidate>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row" ng-repeat="myid in userId">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label>ID</label>
                            <input ng-model="userId[$index].id" id="myid"name="myid" placeholder="Enter bugid" type="text" required readonly disabled>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label>Comments</label>
                            <textarea ng-model="userId[$index].manualcomment" id="textarea1" rows="1" required></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-3 ">
                            <label>Gender</label>

                            <select ng-model="userId[$index].gender" name="select2" required>
                                <option value="male">Male</option>
                                <option value="female">Female</option>

                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttonContainer text-center btn-container">
                <br>
                <button ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" type="button" id="adduser" ng-click="addusers()">Add user</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn button--default btn--small pull-center">Close</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And then in the controller.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
 myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.userId = [1,2,3,4,5] // or new Array(3);

   $sope.adduser = function() {
     var serverData = $scope.userId;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use track by $index in ng-repat and then use the index for models

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="myid in userid track by $index">

<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>ID</label>
                        <input ng-model="userId[$index].id" id="myid"name="myid" placeholder="Enter bugid" type="text" required readonly disabled>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Comments</label>
                        <textarea ng-model="userId[$index].manualcomment" id="textarea1" rows="1" required></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 ">
                        <label>Gender</label>

                        <select ng-model="userId[$index].gender" name="select2" required>
                            <option value="male">Male</option>
                            <option value="female">Female</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
```